# Constrastive vs Counterfactual Explanations

Tags: machine-learning, explainable-ai

Is there any canonical definition for Contrastive vs Counterfactual explanations?

In the literature, I keep reading different versions but I wonder if there are good definitions or illustrative examples. Attempts to get a hold of the two concepts to make indisputable and unambiguous definitions seem to slip between the fingers.

What I have found so far?

- [T. Miller, Contrastive explanation: A structural-model approach (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03163)
- S. Wachter, B. Mittelstadt, and C. Russell, Counterfactual explanations without opening the black box: Automated decisions and the GDPR (2017), Harv. JL & Tech., 31:841.
- [Counterfactual vs Contrastive Explanations in Artificial Intelligence](https://towardsdatascience.com/counterfactual-vs-contrastive-explanations-in-artificial-intelligence-e67a9cfc7e4e)